# Dropdown Menu in compose overlaps system keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a text input with expandable suggestions list in Compose. I'm using ExposedDropdownMenuBox as a container with TextField and ExposedDropdownMenu inside.

```
@Composable
fun ExpirationTimeMenuBox() {
    val suggestions = listOf("Dzień", "Tydzień", "Miesiąc", "Rok", "Dzień")
    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var textFieldValue by remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
    }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = isExpanded,
        onExpandedChange = { isExpanded = !isExpanded },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 4.dp)
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Termin") },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .menuAnchor()
        )
        val filteredSuggestions = if (textFieldValue.text.isEmpty()) {
            emptyList()
        } else {
            suggestions.map { suggestion ->
                "${textFieldValue.text} $suggestion"
            }
        }
        if (filteredSuggestions.isNotEmpty()) {
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = isExpanded,
                onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false },
                modifier = Modifier.exposedDropdownSize(),
            ) {
                filteredSuggestions.forEach { suggestion ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = suggestion) },
                        onClick = {
                            textFieldValue = TextFieldValue(suggestion, selection = TextRange(suggestion.length))
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When ExposedDropdownMenu shows, it overlaps system keyboard.

[image: screenshot]

The expected behaviour is that ExposedDropdownMenu should be shown above TextField when there is no enough space for suggestions. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Did you find out any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @VaralakshmiGanta No. As a workaround I put MenuBox higher and I restrict its max height, to fit the app window and not overlap the keyboard. To do so I use Modifier.heightIn(0.dp, maxDropdownHeight) on ExposedDropdownMenu